# Unity3D android app, UI shows completely black, only once built to Android device

Tags: c#, android, mobile, unity-game-engine

I'm building a 3D virtual pet app for android mobile phones using unity 5.

[Below is a screenshot of the scene while running through unity itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbmkg.jpg)

However when the app is built to my android phone (running android version 5.0.1), the green window on the right is completely black, leaving neither of the two progress bars visible.

Each object is an 'image', added to a canvas.
The Main window is a Green rectangle.
Each progress bar is a black rectangle with a white rectangle on top of that, with another coloured rectangle on top of the white(This re sizes to show progress).

I don't know what could be causing this issue. If there is any further information which could help please let me know, I've been struggling with this issue for a while now.

Comment: Any chance size of image is set above 1024 in sprites settings in inspector? I.e. 2048 or 4096?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck on this same issue were the images took on the expected color in the Unity editor but not when the game was running on my Android phone.

To fix the issue I set the "Source Image" to something. Unity comes with a couple simple images that you can use. Try setting the "Source Image" property of the canvas image to the "UISprite" sprite. Once this is done change the "Image Type" to "Simple" and it should now work on your android phone. Make sure you do this for all three of the images you are using (black, white, and colored).

Comment: Hi Shipps, thanks for this this solved my issue.
I'm curious as to why this happens though? Do you happen to know at all?